# there is no attribute "onLoad"

Tags: html, validation

Can anyone tell me why I am getting **error** when I am validating even through I have the correct doctype?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title></title>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" -->
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../Scripts/AC_RunActiveContent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.registerObject("flashBanner", "9.0.0");
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="InitCaptcha()">
```

**Error**

**Line 21, Column 14: there is no attribute "onLoad"**

You have used the attribute named above in your document, but the document type you are using does not support that attribute for this element. This error is often caused by incorrect use of the "Strict" document type with a document that uses frames (e.g. you must use the "Transitional" document type to get the "target" attribute), or by using vendor proprietary extensions such as "marginheight" (this is usually fixed by using CSS to achieve the desired effect instead).

This error may also result if the element itself is not supported in the document type you are using, as an undefined element will have no supported attributes; in this case, see the element-undefined error message for further information.

How to fix: check the spelling and case of the element and attribute, (Remember XHTML is all lower-case) and/or check that they are both allowed in the chosen document type, and/or use CSS instead of this attribute. If you received this error when using the  element to incorporate flash media in a Web page, see the FAQ item on valid flash.

Comment: Can you give us the error and validation code?

Comment: this is not enough information for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Have you tried `onload` with a small letter `l`?

Comment: it seems their is something wrong with the doctype declaration, create a html page with an editor and check, is it giving the same error. and also check the active run script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to change the **onLoad** attribute inside body to **onload** as XHTML is case-sensitive and it allows only lower-case letters for tags & attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jquery, (which can be turned off) maybe you can try just using the javascript `onload` function... http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: I would -1 for the w3schools link, but wont be mean.

Comment: What’s wrong with this particular reference on the `onload` Event?

Answer (score 0):

I realize the question has already been answered, but I'm going to add in that it is not a good idea to mix your XHTML and JavaScript (e.g. by using the `onload` event attribute).

You can use **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    InitCaptcha();
});
```

Or you can use an **event listener**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        'use strict';
        InitCaptcha();
    }, false);
</script>
```